# Settings CRM systemusers personal options in code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013, settings

At my work we develop new CRM functionalities. Before they are rolled out to our Production environment (On Premises CRM 2013), we have a Development environment to develop the functionalities, a Test environment to test the new functionalities and an Acceptation environment to let the business play with the new functionalities before they go live. After the new functionalities go live, a new Development Environment is created, based of the Production environment (but with scrambled data) and the whole cycle starts again.

Every environment (except Production ofcourse) is a new, fresh environment. We have a list of around 30 users that are used for debuggin and testing the new functionalities. These users have to be added to the new environment every time. And with around 30 users, adding them to the AD, setting up their teams, roles, mailboxes, etc.. this became a very time consuming, and prone to errors, task.

Now I've build a tool in C# that reads a .csv data table with all the users, their roles, teams and mailbox settings. Then the tool adds the users to the AD and to CRM. This all works great, except for one small thing:

Some of the users are used to send emails through (via workflows). To allow others to send emails on their behalf, those users have to have the option 'Allow other Microsoft Dynamics CRM users to send email on your behalf' set in their Personal Options. I can do this manually, but I would like to set this checkbox while creating the users with my program.

So my question is: Is it possible to set the option 'Allow other Microsoft Dynamics CRM users to send email on your behalf' in C# when I'm creating the users?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the "IsSendAllowed" property to true on the particular user's setting.

```
 foreach (var userId in yourListOfUserIds)
 {
    var userSetting = new UserSettings()
    {
       SystemUserId = userId, 
       IsSendAsAllowed = true //set the flag to true
    };
    organizationService.Update(userSetting);
 }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! (had to change 'false' into 'true' because the setting needs to be enabled). Thank you very much!

Comment: Overlooked the boolean value, updated the answer, thanks